# Is every function on the plane that satisfies this mixed convexity condition convex?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

$\newcommand{\half}{\frac{1}{2}}$

Let $g:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ be a smooth symmetric function, i.e. $g(x,y)=g(y,x)$ for every $x,y$. Suppose that
$$
g\left( \half(x,y)+\half(y,x) \right) \le \half g(x,y)+\half g(y,x) =g(x,y), \tag{1}
$$
for every $x,y$ or equivalently
$$
g(x,y) \ge g(\frac{x + y}{2}, \frac{x + y}{2}) . 
$$

Is $g$ midpoint convex?

That is, does
$$
g(\frac{u + v}{2}) \le \frac{g(u) + g(v)}{2} \tag{2}
$$
for every $u,v \in \mathbb R^2$?

Condition $(1)$ is more specific than $(2)$ since in inequality $(1)$, $u=(x,y),v=(y,x)$ are related to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample: let $g(x, y) = (x - y)^2 + (x + y)^3$. Then $g$ is clearly smooth, and $g(x, y) = g(y, x)$. We have,
$$g(x, y) - g\left(\frac{x + y}{2}, \frac{x + y}{2}\right) = (x - y)^2 + (x + y)^3 - (x + y)^3 \ge 0,$$
hence $g$ satisfies the premises of the question. But $g$ is not midpoint convex. If we take $u = (0, 0)$ and $v = (-2, -2)$, then,
\begin{align*}
g\left(\frac{u + v}{2}\right) &= g(-1, -1) = -8 \\
\frac{g(u) + g(v)}{2} &= \frac{0 - 64}{2} = -32 < g\left(\frac{u + v}{2}\right).
\end{align*}

Comment: This is a perfect answer, thanks. I wonder how did you think about that (I understand how you could come up with the "cancellation idea" that makes $g(x, y) - g\left(\frac{x + y}{2}, \frac{x + y}{2}\right) \ge 0$, but I don't immediately see how you were able to conjure a non-convex example satisfying this. Is there an "immediate", straightforward way, to see that this function is not convex?

Comment: @Asaf The idea is pretty simple: write the function in the form $p(x - y) + q(x + y)$. So long as $p$ was even and convex, we would get the symmetry and midpoint convexity properties you wanted. I only needed to make $q$ non-convex. Now that I think of it, choosing $q(z) = -z^2$ is a simpler choice, which will produce the function $g(x, y) = -4xy$, which is a simpler counterexample.